# Use session bean to hold datasource connection

Tags: java, datasource, jsf-2.2, session-bean

I have made a database wrapper in java to connect to a datasource. The way I connect to the datasource is with the following line:

```
DB db = new DB();
```

Then I can just start doing queries like

```
db.setQuery("select * from...");
db.setParams(String...);
db.executeQuery();
```

Is it ok to hold that db object on a session scoped bean and then access that object from other request scoped beans that are form controllers?

I think that there's a better way of doing it than create a new `DB` instance every time the form's bean is requested.

I'm not using any persistence API.

Comment: how are you obtaining the DB connections? I guess you're using a pool, aren't you?

Comment: @mrod yes, I'm using the Tomcat connection pool.

Comment: The duplicate holds true for keeping the connection in session scope as well.

Comment: but is it your DB class holding a single connection or is it getting a new one each time you call executeQuery(..) or something... ? Can you post the code of that class?

Comment: "The duplicate?", can you clarify? @BalusC

Comment: See top of question.

Comment: So, is it bad / worst to have the connection on session scoped?